# How do i fetch changes from server on TFS if SYNC is not available?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

On google it says that I need the option 'SYNC', but I can't find it in my Team Explorer tab.

This is all the options that I have available.

[image]

I looked into the 'Pending Changes', but I have no idea how to only fetch and not merge my changes or pull and delete everything that I've done.

For what I understand, 'Included Chenges' are my modifications. 'Excluded Changes' I think that are my team's modifications, that I actually need.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're in a TFVC repo and not a git Repo. TFVC doesn't have a <kbd>Sync</kbd> option. Azure DevOps supports both kinds, but the UI and how you'd use them is different.

Instead you can perform a <kbd>Get latest</kbd> from the solution explorer and the Source control explorer. Then do a check-in to send your local changes off to the server.

These options are also available from the <kbd>File</kbd> - <kbd>Source Control</kbd> - <kbd>Get latest</kbd> menu in the top level menu.